# ROS Android Apps: can't add a robot on Kindle Fire

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Edit:** Added better screenshot

Hello all,

Please forgive what I'm sure is a silly question, but it has me stumped.

I have a rooted Kindle Fire with the ROS apps from the Google Android Market installed.  I started the app and it prompts me to add a robot.  I typed in the IP address of the robot, but there's no "ok" button to click and no "enter" button showing on the keyboard (the "enter" key is context sensitive on the Fire and doesn't show up if it's not mapped to any action).  The Fire doesn't have a camera, so I can't use the QR code option either.  I don't have any other android devices available to figure out how the dialog is supposed to work.

Here's a screenshot

[image: image description]

So, I can't figure out how to say "ok" and get the ROS app to add my robot.  Any suggestions?  I'm comfortable editing a file or something if that's what it takes.

Sorry for what seems like a silly question, but I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance,
-Brian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12622/ros-android-apps:-can%27t-add-a-robot-on-kindle-fire/) by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on 2012-01-13**:
Letting me know how the app is supposed to work (are you supposed to press "enter"?) would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out a workaround.

So... the ROS android app is expecting the "enter" key to be pressed, but for some reason the Fire doesn't realize that and isn't showing the enter key.

However, you can use the android debugger (or a terminal application) to simulate keypresses on android.  See here: [Simulating Keypresses on Android](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.com/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html)

You need to use the input command to send code 66 (enter).

On your laptop type this after you have entered the ip address of the robot.

$ adb shell input 66

A more permanent solution would be adding an "ok" button to the dialog

---

Originally posted by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) with karma: 183 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on 2012-01-14**:
Great. Thanks!  I'm happy to do further testing on the Fire if the devs need it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-13**:
I've filed a bug on the android app to get this fixed: https://kforge.ros.org/appmanandroid/trac/ticket/27